# Declaring as an existing array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Before you read this code and get exhausted, just know its an open source JavaScript library called p5.js

https://p5js.org/reference/

I have the basic package and no add-on's. just look at this...

```
var weapons = {
    //[WEAPON NAME]: [accuracy,repeat,recoil,recoilmax,recoil-recovery,damage,firerate,reloadspeed],
    M4A1: [10, 10, 0.2, 5, 1],

    //primary: weapons.M4A1,//ERROR
    //secondary: weapons.M4A1,//ERROR
    equipped: weapons.M4A1,
};

var inventory = {
  accuracy: weapons.M4A1[0],
  accuracyREF: 10,
  recoil: 0.2,
  recoilMAX: 3,
  recoilRecovery: 1,
  damage: 1,
  fireRate: 1,
};
```

Shows a blank screen till i get rid of the line that declares weapons.equipped

I ALSO TRIED USING SPLICE AS SHOWN BELOW IN p5.JS syntax SAME GOES FOR arrayCopy()

```
var weapons = {
  //[WEAPON NAME]: [accuracy,repeat,recoil,recoilmax,recoil-recovery,damage,firerate,reloadspeed],
  M4A1: [10, 10, 0.2, 5, 1],

  //primary: weapons.M4A1,//ERROR
  //secondary: weapons.M4A1,//ERROR
  equipped: [0,0,0,0,0],
};

splice(weapons.M4A1, equipped, 0);

var inventory = {
  accuracy: weapons.M4A1[0],
  accuracyREF: 10,
  recoil: 0.2,
  recoilMAX: 3,
  recoilRecovery: 1,
  damage: 1,
  fireRate: 1,
};
```

This is essential for my game and I will have to abandon it if this cant be done

Comment: No experience with p5, or the rest of your code, but it looks like you're trying to access the `weapons` object before it is instantiated. Look at your console...what error message are you getting. I expect you'll see something like "cannot read property 'M4A1' of undefined".

Comment: sketch.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'M4A1' of undefined
    at sketch.js:85
(anonymous) @ sketch.js:85
sketch.js:116 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accuracy' of undefined
    at getAccuracy (sketch.js:116)
    at draw (sketch.js:153)
    at e.redraw (p5.min.js:8)
    at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:7)
    at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:7)
    at new e (p5.min.js:7)
    at e (p5.min.js:7)

Comment: removal of the equipped or splice will make it fix.. why the accuracy one?

Comment: Should I add my entire game?

Comment: Check this out to access `weapons` without the necessity to add the referencing properties after initialization: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var weapons` fails because you're trying to assign one of it's properties to itself and it doesn't exist yet. Therefore `var inventory` fails because `weapons` is undefined due to the first error.

To understand what's happening, start here:

```
var weapons = {
  M4A1: [10, 10, 0.2, 5, 1],
  equipped: weapons.M4A1 // <-- weapons.M4A1 must be determined first
};
// weapons === undefined
```

Before instantiating `var weapons` JS needs to process the value of  `weapons.M4A1` in order to assign to `equipped`. The problem is `weapons` does not exist yet.

Next you're trying to instantiate `inventory`.

```
// remember, weapons === undefined
var inventory = {
  accuracy: weapons.M4A1[0], // again, weapons.M4A1[0] must be determined
  accuracyREF: 10,
  ...
};
// inventory === undefined
```

...therefore, `inventory` also fails to instantiate.

---

Attempt #2: `splice(weapons.M4A1, equipped, 0);`

[p5/splice](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/splice) states `splice` is for arrays, not objects, (among other problems with your implementation).

---

Can you do this?

```
var weapons = {
  M4A1: [10, 10, 0.2, 5, 1],
  equipped: [10, 10, 0.2, 5, 1]
};

var inventory = {
  accuracy: weapons.M4A1[0],
  ...
};
```

Or this?

```
var weapons = {
  M4A1: [10, 10, 0.2, 5, 1],
  equipped: [0,0,0,0,0]
};
weapons.equipped = weapons.M4A1;

var inventory = {
  accuracy: weapons.M4A1[0],
  ...
};
```

Comment: I will try the second one but the first one would make it awkward to change the weapon later

Comment: You could use `weapons.equipped = weapons.M4A1.slice()` to make   `M4A1` and `equipped` different arrays - and prevent updating one of them from updating the other because they refer to the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [getter functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). For an explanation why errors occur just check the answer of @bloodyKnuckles.

```js
var weapons = {
  //[WEAPON NAME]: [accuracy,repeat,recoil,recoilmax,recoil-recovery,damage,firerate,reloadspeed],
  M4A1: [10, 10, 0.2, 5, 1],
  get primary() {
    return weapons.M4A1
  },
  get secondary() {
    return weapons.M4A1
  },
  get equipped() {
    return weapons.M4A1
  },
};

var inventory = {
  accuracy: weapons.M4A1[0],
  accuracyREF: 10,
  recoil: 0.2,
  recoilMAX: 3,
  recoilRecovery: 1,
  damage: 1,
  fireRate: 1,
};

console.log("weapons", weapons);
console.log("inventory", inventory);
```